# Circuit find IB, IC and VCE?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, circuit-design, waveform

I'm asked to find IB, IC and VCE.
[image: ode]

This is my answer:

[image: my answer is true are not ,VCE Value is nagative is it true are not]

I wonder if my answer is true are not. VCE Value is negative, is this true or not?

Comment: Apply KVL properly for calculating base current.

Comment: @SadatRafi see answer is true or not value of VCE is negative

Comment: Already the first [formula](https://imgur.com/a/afN3jBx) is incomplete. A relatively large value was left out.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem this is a discussion site. Plus my comment directly indicates that your answer should be incorrect.

Comment: @Sadat, "*this is a discussion site*". No, it's a question and answer site. It's quite specifically not for discussion (even though that's what I'm doing here). Hmmm.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem  Here you find the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923

Comment: Can someone please acknowledge that the OP actually showed his own attempt at a solution, rather than simply posting the question and saying "What is the answer?" +1 for showing your own work, even if it is incorrect. Well done!

Comment: You say RB = R1||R2. R1 and R2 are not marked in the diagram ? the **kilo** in R1 and R2 are not mentioned in the calculations. IB was calculated as 0.955 **milli** ampere (calculation is probly wrong)). But in next step of finding IC, the **milli** was lost.

Comment: Your transistor symbols do not represents BJTs. BJT has arrows to differentiate between  NPN and PNP types. They are important.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your notes correctly out of 12V supply you got Vce of about 21KV? Looking at Ib assuming you get about 1mA and you multiply by beta of 100 therfore you get 100mA not 100A.Please check how you calculated Ib again.

To answer your question Vce in this circuit cannot be negative with 12V supply at collector and ground at emitter resistor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: answer part A]*[![thankyou i am done][2]][2]*

thanyou

Answer (score 0):

[image: part 2 answer]

answer part 2
thanyou i am done

Comment: “answer part 2 thanyou i am done”? This is not very polite way to ask someone for help. Users of this forum help others out of their own good will. Therefore, attitude that they own you answer is wrong. I can help you with hints and ideas but it is your home/course work. So, please be polite and ask specific question.