# How do I perform ac analysis of common emitter with voltage divider feedback?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, negative-feedback

I'm working towards understanding voltage-shunt feedback. I'm about halfway there, and stuck.  I am  building a simple common emitter with voltage divider feedback.
[image]
I managed to get it biased to put the collector at 6V and have 3.4mA quiescent current.
I modeled it with hybrid-pi and have what seem like reasonable values for gm and r-pi.
[image]
Unfortunately, the basic algebra I used to solve voltage-series and current-series problems doesn't seem to work here.  What analysis method could I use to help me answer a question like "for an input current of 100uA, what output voltage/current should I expect?"
As I said, I was able to solve questions like this without too much trouble when it was the common emitter with degeneration or the emitter follower.  But that pesky \$R_F\$ resistor messes with my feeble mind!

Comment: Have you tried nodal analysis? There seems to be only two nodes. Only two equations to solve, I think.

Comment: Is your signal source an actual current source? Or really just a voltage source (without a stated source impedance), like what is usually placed in the schematic at that location?

Comment: Also, for the quiescent point (I know you are only looking at the small signal arrangement and that you feel you already have the operating point nailed) you could examine [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/530159/38098) recent post as a double-check on your work.

Comment: You should consider setting up the circuit so that there is an input resistor in series with the capacitor driven from a voltage source then, the AC gain is approximately \$\dfrac{-R_f}{R_{IN}}\$ but don't expect practical voltage gains more than about 40.

Comment: Nuggethead, I get \$A_v\approx -230\$ from your model there. (I assume the input is a voltage and the output is a voltage.) What do you get?

Comment: @nuggethead For a circuit like yours, \$A_v\approx -g_m\cdot R_{_\textbf{C}}\$. The more detailed answer from your given model would be, \$A_v\approx -\left(g_m-\frac1{R_{_\textbf{F}}}\right)\cdot \left(R_{_\textbf{C}}\mid\mid R_{_\textbf{F}}\right)\$. But I think you can see why that can be simplified, given your values. (The reason the simulation gain is different is because your model is not a complete one -- also, you may need to specify a very small input signal. How small of one are you using?)

Comment: What would my model need to be complete?  I'm using an input of 20 mV.

Comment: @nuggethead Are you aware of the bulk impedance at the base?

Comment: Never heard of it - I'll add it to my "to study" list.  Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: @nuggethead One of the things you will learn (if not already knowing it) is that no one depends on exact calculations. You don't need to struggle hard to calculate -200 instead of -230. In the end, you use negative-feedback and quite different topologies which make that work well to get the actual gain you want. Looking at individual stages in isolation just isn't done much. High gain and NFB fixes all ills.

Comment: @jonk thank you once again.  I understand that NFB is more useful than long calculations of individual stages.  I attempted using the high gain/NFB approach and discovered I didn't understand these foundational skills, hence this dive into discrete stages.  Truly appreciate you taking time to explain!

Comment: @nuggethead Then focus on using local NFB. (Emitter degeneration, to start with.) Also, as a next step, consider simple 2nd-BJT additions which provide NFB to create a composite single-stage and a few more benefits than just one stage's emitter degeneration resistor can provide. These are incremental steps. Best wishes.

Comment: @jonk can you show me an example of a simple 2nd bjt addition?

Comment: @nuggethead I can. But it is difficult through commentary here. But for one to consider, think of using an emitter follower at the collector output and then using that follower's emitter to feed back to the first BJT. Also, I list some single-BJT stage topologies [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/436341/38098). I don't know if it would be an appropriate place to post an example here as a answer. But it would allow me to show some, that way.