# Large signal model analysis of npn BJT

Tags: bjt, npn, analysis

I have the following circuit and I am trying to find V<sub>B</sub>, V<sub>E</sub>, and V<sub>C</sub>, and consequently I<sub>B</sub> & I<sub>C</sub>. The "hints" I am given are (1) to assume that *v<sub>s</sub>* has a DC value of 0V, (2) to use the large-signal BJT model, and (3) I can neglect C<sub>E</sub>.
[image]

From what I understand, the equivalent large-signal model for an npn BJT in the forward active region (that is assuming the setup above is in forward active region) is shown below: [image]

Now given that the DC value of *v<sub>s</sub>* is 0, and applying KVL to the base-emitter loop (also assuming that V<sub>BE</sub> = 0.7V), I'm getting V<sub>B</sub> = -5V and V<sub>E</sub> = -5.7V. Now before I go further, I have a gut feeling that this is wrong, but I'm having a hard time understanding why. My thought is that since *v<sub>s</sub>* has 0V<sub>DC</sub>, V<sub>B</sub> should be 0 as well?

The theory behind BJT operation is a major point of weakness for me so any help is appreciated!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faSLY6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the circuit I performed the KVL on based on the hints given to me and the assumption I made that the BJT is in forward active region.

Comment: Maybe you should spell out exactly how you applied KVL to get those numbers. I see two unknown voltages (without making simplifying assumptions).

Comment: Why do you think that the voltage at the base will be equal to VB = -5V if vs is 0V?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I added the schematic I performed KVL on, which as I'm looking at it again I can see that it gets me nowhere. I also forgot to add that I was given another hint that 0V = V_R2 + V_BE + V_Rbias

Comment: Can you apply KCL and KVL at the same time?  Because your equivalent circuit looks correct.

Comment: @G36 Thank you for your input and sorry for not clarifying, but yes I'm not constrained to just performing KVL. I haven't applied KCL to the full model yet, though. I'll try that now thank you

Comment: I meant something like this:  Vee = V_R2 + Vbe + R_E thus Vee = IbR2 + Vbe + IeR_E

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to proceed with that sorry. I would think that V_B is needed to get I_B? And I_E = I_B + I_C, which according to the large_signal model: I_C is dependent on I_B.

Comment: For the BJT we have \$I_E = I_B + I_C = I_B + β I_B = (β + 1)I_B\$ Thus, we can solve for Ib or Ie. Try to analyze this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923   and maybe you should try to read this as well https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355899/how-is-possible-that-with-same-ibase-there-is-more-than-one-vce/355955#355955