Voltage gain calculation
I need to calculate the voltage gain of this circuit.
Q1) As I understand, the voltage gain can be calculated as ((10k//47k//33k)/re1) * (4.7k / (1/100 * (10k//47k//33k) + re2)). (assumed 4.7ks are bypassed) However, since there are no re1 or re2 resistors in this circuit, the voltage gain theoretically approaches infinity. Is it correct?
Q2) When I simulated the circuit with a Vin of 200uV, Vout was 5.76V, resulting in a voltage gain of 14400. Why is there a discrepancy between the theoretical gain and the simulation result?"






Could you tell us the quiescent collector currents from your simulation? Set the signal source to 0V amplitude, then read out the current flowing through the collectors of both transistors.

$re$ is not a real ohmic resistance. And it has nothing to do with R_E you have entered into the transistor mode. You do not have to enter the $re$ value into the circuit simulator. The simulator will calculate $re$ himself.

@G36 Thanks! I totally understood.

All you need to do is to set R_E back to 0 ohm and set B_F to 100.

Because your assumption about \$r_e\$ is wrong.
Because \$r_e\$ is the slope of \$V_{BE} = f(I_e)\$.
$$r_e = \frac{dV_{BE}}{dI_E} = \frac{V_T}{I_E}$$
Where: \$V_T\$ is a so-called thermal voltage \$V_T = \frac{kT}{q}\$ a semiconductor physics constants. And is approximately \$26mV\$ at room temps for small signal BJTs.
This means that the \$r_e\$ is a "property" of a transistor alone.
For the first stage will have \$r_{e1} \approx \frac{26mV}{I_{E1}} \approx 26\Omega \$
and  the second stage \$r_{e2}\approx \frac{26mV}{I_{E2}} \approx 13\Omega\$

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Therefore, the amplifier voltage gain will be equal to
$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} \approx \frac{R_{C1}||R_3||R_4||(\beta + 1)r_{e2}}{r_{e1}} \times \frac{R_{C2}}{r_{e2}} \approx 40 \times 360 \approx 14400 \: V/V $$
To calculate the transistor quiescent current I used this simple approach.
I have assumed that resistance \$R_{E1}\$ is "transform into the base side" and is equal to \$\beta * R_{E1} = 470k\Omega\$. Thus, this is the load resistance seen by the voltage divider.

simulate this circuit
Therefore the voltage at the base is equal to:
$$V_B = Vcc * \frac{R_2||(\beta * R_{E1})}{R_1 + R_2||(\beta * R_{E1})} = 25V * \frac{42k\Omega}{150k\Omega + 42k\Omega} \approx 5.4V$$
Since we know the base voltage, we can easily find the emitter quiescent current.
$$I_{E1} = \frac{V_{B1} - V_{BE1}}{R_{E1}} = \frac{5.4V - 0.7V}{4.7k\Omega} = 1mA $$
A similar approach can be applied to solve for \$I_{E2}\$ quiescent current.

Nice answer! It might be worth explaining why you included the (beta+1)re2 term in Q1's collector load, though, since it might not be obvious to everyone that Q2's input impedance is loading down the first amplifier stage significantly.

@JonathanS. How did you get Vt = 26mV??

@abeloejmn $V_T$ is a thermal voltage $V_T=\frac{k T}{q}$ and is approximately $26:\textrm{mV}$ at room temps, that for small signal BJTs. So 25mV or 26mV is a reasonable value for room temperature V_T  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#The_thermal_voltage

I see. I'm sorry to keep asking, then how did you get I_E

I_E is an emitter current of a given transistor.  For example, for  I_E1 I used a simplified approach.  I_E1 = V_E1/RE1 where V_E1 = ( ( 25V * (47k||1004.7k)/(150k + (47k||1004.7k) )) - 0.7V) = ( (25V * 42/(150 + 42)) - 0.7V ) = 4.7V Thus I_E1 = 4.7V/4.7k = 1mA. For mere take a look here  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923

When I add re1(26ohm) and re2(13ohm) in each transistor, simulated voltage gain(9400) is far less than the theoretical value(14400). Why does the difference occur??

I do not understand what you have done. Why do you add resistors to the circuit? Maybe try to update the question. And show us what you have done.

(I attached the image to the main text.) I performed the simulation by modifying the Re values of Q1 and Q2 to 26ohm and 13ohm, respectively, and when looking at the frequency response, the voltage gain is calculated to be about 76dBv(=9000). On the other hand, as you told me, it is about 14400 when considering the Re values theoretically, and I wonder why this difference occurs.

@ abeloejmn - I dislike the model (and the calculation) with this "magic resistance re" . This is because - in fact - it is not a resistance at all. I suppose you have made the following error: You have used both re values as a feedback resistance - and this is completely wrong. As I have told you: It is not a resistance !! It is nothing else than a mathematical expression: re=1/gm. Here, the quantity gm is the transconductance which relates input voltage changes to correcponding output current changes. My recommendation: In all equations, replace re with 1/gm. This is the most logical step.

@LvW Thanks!!!!

@ abeloejmn  - I really don`t know who was the inventor of this - in my opinion - totally misleading small-signal diagram using a part called re. Very often, this is a source of misunderstandings. I think, this equivalent diagram (called T-diagram) is really superfluous becaus there are two other well working diagrams (based on a current source controlled either by "beta" or by "gm")
